# How can i connect firebase to flutter app?

Tags: android-studio, flutter

please help me connect firebase to my flutter application. When I asked this question, I found information on the internet https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/overview/.
But I didn't understand anything since the second step, help me please.

> Install the plugin by running the following command from your project root directory:

```
$ flutter pub get.
```

Comment: It means that you have to open the Terminal tab in Android Studio/VS Code & type the command `flutter pub get`, then press Enter. This command will get all the dependencies that are mentioned in your `pubspec.yaml`. Also, you can watch YouTube videos if you are not able to follow the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create Firebase project
   [Firebase console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Vb5u.png)

You will have to enter project name, account, choose the coutry etc.

2. After you create your project, choose the desired platform that you want to use firebase on (Android in this case)
   [Register App on firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dO8w0.png)
3. Then you register your application, by writing your applicationId in the required form

This is where your apllicationId is located --> [AplicationId location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aAVrn.png)

4. Download google-services.json and put it in the App folder (Nicely shown on the firebase webpage)
5. Then you will have to make some changes to gradle files I think (it's nicely shown on
   firebase page, nothing exceptionally hard)
6. You add firebase to your pubspec.yaml file ( firebase_core: "Version that you want")
7. run `$ flutter pub get`
8. Last thing before using firebase, you must initialize App,

   final Future _initialization = Firebase.initializeApp();

put this line somewhere, I suggest in MaterialApp before the application is built.

Answer (score 0):

$ flutter pub get

simply means It will install the package for you. In vs code you don't need to do anything just add the package in pubspec.yaml and save it. Automatically flutter pub get will run for you. and if it is not run automatically just type flutter pub get in terminal and it will install the package for you.