# Flutter - Get location from another user and show it on a map for the customer user

Tags: android, ios, flutter, google-maps

I'm devoloping an uber like app that I need to show the "driver" location to the user and track it in real time, I was able to track the location but just from the user and I'm out of ideias, tried watching some videos and getting some codes but its my first flutter app.
Here's the current code that I'm using to get the user location but trying to get the "driver".

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_polyline_points/flutter_polyline_points.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:hapdog/constants.dart';
import 'package:location/location.dart';
import 'package:hapdog/services/google_map_api.dart';

class MapScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const MapScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  static const String id = 'map_screen';

  @override
  _MapScreenState createState() => _MapScreenState();
}

class _MapScreenState extends State<MapScreen> {
  late BitmapDescriptor pinLocationIcon;

  LatLng sourceLocation = LatLng(28.432864, 77.002563);
  LatLng destinationLatlng = LatLng(28.431626, 77.002475);

  Completer<GoogleMapController> _controller = Completer();

  Set<Marker> _marker = Set<Marker>();

  Set<Polyline> _polylines = Set<Polyline>();
  List<LatLng> polylineCoordinates = [];
  late PolylinePoints polylinePoints;

  late StreamSubscription<LocationData> subscription;

  LocationData? currentLocation;
  late LocationData destinationLocation;
  late Location location;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    BitmapDescriptor.fromAssetImage(
            const ImageConfiguration(), 'assets/dog_icon.png')
        .then((onValue) {
      pinLocationIcon = onValue;
    });

    location = Location();
    polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();

    subscription = location.onLocationChanged.listen((clocation) {
      currentLocation = clocation;

      updatePinsOnMap();
    });

    setInitialLocation();
  }

  void setInitialLocation() async {
    await location.getLocation().then((value) {
      currentLocation = value;
      setState(() {});
    });
    destinationLatlng = LatLng(
        currentLocation!.latitude ?? 0.0, currentLocation!.longitude ?? 0.0);

    destinationLocation = LocationData.fromMap({
      "latitude": destinationLatlng.latitude,
      "longitude": destinationLatlng.longitude,
    });
  }

  void showLocationPins() {
    var sourceposition = LatLng(
        currentLocation!.latitude ?? 0.0, currentLocation!.longitude ?? 0.0);

    var destinationPosition =
        LatLng(destinationLatlng.latitude, destinationLatlng.longitude);

    // _marker.add(Marker(
    //   icon: pinLocationIcon,
    //   markerId: MarkerId('sourcePosition'),
    //   position: sourceposition,
    // ));

    // _marker.add(
    //   Marker(
    //     icon: pinLocationIcon,
    //     markerId: MarkerId('destinationPosition'),
    //     position: destinationPosition,
    //   ),
    // );
  }

  void setPolylines() async {
    PolylineResult result = await polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
        kGoogleAPIKey,
        PointLatLng(currentLocation!.latitude ?? 0.0,
            currentLocation!.longitude ?? 0.0),
        PointLatLng(destinationLatlng.latitude, destinationLatlng.longitude));

    if (result.status == 'OK') {
      result.points.forEach((PointLatLng point) {
        polylineCoordinates.add(LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
      });

      setState(() {
        _polylines.add(Polyline(
            width: 10,
            polylineId: PolylineId('polyLine'),
            color: Color(0xFF08A5CB),
            points: polylineCoordinates));
      });
    }
  }

  void updatePinsOnMap() async {
    CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition(
      zoom: 19,
      bearing: 30,
      target: LatLng(
          currentLocation!.latitude ?? 0.0, currentLocation!.longitude ?? 0.0),
    );

    final GoogleMapController controller = await _controller.future;

    controller.animateCamera(CameraUpdate.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

    var sourcePosition = LatLng(
        currentLocation!.latitude ?? 0.0, currentLocation!.longitude ?? 0.0);

    setState(() {
      _marker.removeWhere((marker) => marker.mapsId.value == 'sourcePosition');

      _marker.add(Marker(
        icon: pinLocationIcon,
        markerId: MarkerId('sourcePosition'),
        position: sourcePosition,
      ));
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    CameraPosition initialCameraPosition = CameraPosition(
      zoom: 15,
      bearing: 30,
      target: currentLocation != null
          ? LatLng(currentLocation!.latitude ?? 0.0,
              currentLocation!.longitude ?? 0.0)
          : LatLng(0.0, 0.0),
    );

    return currentLocation == null
        ? Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          )
        : SafeArea(
            child: Scaffold(
              body: GoogleMap(
                myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                compassEnabled: true,
                markers: _marker,
                polylines: _polylines,
                mapType: MapType.normal,
                initialCameraPosition: initialCameraPosition,
                onMapCreated: (GoogleMapController controller) {
                  _controller.complete(controller);
                  showLocationPins();
                  setPolylines();
                },
              ),
            ),
          );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    subscription.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Comment: Check out this flutter [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64780007/how-can-i-connect-firebase-to-flutter-app) which has information on Firebase to share information between users.

Comment: @Gardener thanks, I'll check it out, but I was avoiding using firebase, I'm using an API that has a MySQL database already created, I've looked into something related to firebase but like I've said, I was avoiding creating another database.